# Advanced custom fields and post types

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I've made a quick plugin to be used for one site only (over several domains, but same theme, plugins and content). On one of the sites I'm getting an error saying

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
>   /httpd.www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525

On all other installs it's working without any problems.

The code I've added to the plugin is:

```
include_once( 'acf.php' );
define( 'ACF_LITE', true );

function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'menyside',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Menysider' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Menyside' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => false,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'meny'),
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
            )
        );
    }
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'acf_fields' ) );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails','menyside');

if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array (
    'key' => 'group_56b90ec45265a',
    'title' => 'menufields',
    'fields' => array (
        array ( 

...... (continued, data from PHP output from ACF)
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: This code gave me cancer.

Comment: There's... a lot wrong there O.o . There are non-terminated arrays, conditionals, and functions - you're using `$this` outside of a instantiable class (probably the source of the error, but hard to say without a full stack trace - consider trying some of the basic WordPress troubleshooting steps like enabling `WP_DEBUG`). Please review "How to Ask" in our help center for some ways to improve your question.

Comment: 'acf_fields' is not defined anywhere. It should be a valid callback meaning; we should see it here as a defined function.

Comment: I'm learning still -- this is something that lives in my localhost atm. and deployed to a few test sites. Comments like the one from N00b above does not help me or anyone else searching for this in the future. 

Thanks jgraup. I'll look up the issues you've listed in my resources and see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

like people said there is probably a lot of things wrong with your code. so lets start line by line.

whether this is a plugin or a file inside a theme `include_once( 'acf.php' );` im assuming you have that file in the same directory as the current file otherwise you are including it wrong.

this `define( 'ACF_LITE', true );` needs to happen before it is every define or before it is used/called.

as mentioned before `$this` in `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'acf_fields' ) );` can't be called outside a class same goes for `&$this` it is used to refer back to the class, 'act_fields' being your function/method in that class

you really don't need this `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails','menyside');`
you are already adding the support when you are creating the post type above.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. I will look into this tonight. I'm still learning php.